# Trying to iterate all combinations but getting duplicates

Tags: python

I need to generate all possible combinations from lists of weapon, armor, trinket, pet.

I need them in sets of 3, meaning 3 "players" that each have one of the above items, no player can have the same item as another player.

I'm trying to generate all the combinations 3 players can have from the given choices, with the intent of running though a function to eventually determine which item distribution would produce the best outcome in the game.

I have some code working, but I am getting duplicate items, like in my example code where you see in combol[0] they all have the same axe and that is what I'm trying to avoid.

```
import random

def grand():
  return random.randrange(0, 10000)

weapons = [
  ["Ad axe", "Axe", grand() , grand(), grand()],
  ["Stinky sword", "Sword", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Purple Magic Stick", "Staff", grand(), grand(), grand()]
  ]

armor = [
  ["Purple Blazer", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Stinky Coat", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Red Robe", grand(), grand(), grand()]
]

trinkets = [
  ["Moist Coin", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Stinky Chowder", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Red Rock", grand(), grand(), grand()]
]

pets = [
  ["Moist Dragon", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Stinky Cat", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Red Racoon", grand(), grand(), grand()]
]

import itertools

perm = itertools.product(weapons,armor,trinkets,pets)
perml = list(perm)
combo = itertools.permutations(perml,3)
combol = list(combo)

print len(perml)
print len(combol)

def forx(pants):
  for x in pants:
    print x

def inspector(pants):
  for x in pants:
    forx(x)
    print ""

print "combol[0]"
inspector(combol[0])
print "combol[1]"
inspector(combol[1])
```

```
combol[0]
['Ad axe', 'Axe', 7125, 9777, 6994]
['Purple Blazer', 9479, 8226, 8376]
['Moist Coin', 76, 64, 4694]
['Moist Dragon', 868, 9005, 117]

['Ad axe', 'Axe', 7125, 9777, 6994]
['Purple Blazer', 9479, 8226, 8376]
['Moist Coin', 76, 64, 4694]
['Stinky Cat', 4081, 2507, 4474]

['Ad axe', 'Axe', 7125, 9777, 6994]
['Purple Blazer', 9479, 8226, 8376]
['Moist Coin', 76, 64, 4694]
['Red Racoon', 9434, 8935, 2005]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a zip to select each element from the `weapons,armor,trinkets,pets` all at once and them make a combination

```
import random

def grand():
  return random.randrange(0, 10000)

weapons = [
  ["Ad axe", "Axe", grand() , grand(), grand()],
  ["Stinky sword", "Sword", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Purple Magic Stick", "Staff", grand(), grand(), grand()]
  ]

armor = [
  ["Purple Blazer", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Stinky Coat", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Red Robe", grand(), grand(), grand()]
]

trinkets = [
  ["Moist Coin", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Stinky Chowder", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Red Rock", grand(), grand(), grand()]
]

pets = [
  ["Moist Dragon", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Stinky Cat", grand(), grand(), grand()],
  ["Red Racoon", grand(), grand(), grand()]
]

combos=list(zip(weapons,armor,trinkets,pets))
for index,combo in enumerate(combos):
  print "combo ",index + 1
  for element in combo:
    print element
  print
```

OUTPUT

```
combo  1
['Ad axe', 'Axe', 5331, 5696, 9868]
['Purple Blazer', 5327, 8935, 1790]
['Moist Coin', 2760, 1711, 4221]
['Moist Dragon', 6795, 6286, 2978]

combo  2
['Stinky sword', 'Sword', 5286, 7823, 4969]
['Stinky Coat', 2891, 7038, 9630]
['Stinky Chowder', 6799, 6348, 4364]
['Stinky Cat', 1529, 9904, 4510]

combo  3
['Purple Magic Stick', 'Staff', 8290, 5438, 1440]
['Red Robe', 5234, 9325, 7550]
['Red Rock', 229, 4118, 5613]
['Red Racoon', 9673, 9777, 1662]
```

Comment: Albin, the issue is not the values are the same, the same item SHOULD have the same stats, the issue is multiple characters are using the same weapon concurrently.

Comment: @user3552664 I have changed the code, no combo has same element now.